# Input a specific render slot in compositor?

Tags: rendering, render-layers, render-border

Is there a way to **have the compositor input specific slots from the render window**?
My goal would be to achieve a very important feature I had, for example, with Vray: **to render a patch over an already rendered image, without losing it**.
Now, with Cycles, if you render a border (called region in vray), any previously render image will be wiped out. Yet, there are those promising slots, so that I could render an image in slot 1, then, if needed, render a patch in slot 2, and the previous render would still be in slot 1.
So, I was wondering, there must be a way to use an input a node like "image" or "render image" and choose which slot I want from the render window. That way, I could compose a patch rendering without having to re-render a whole 4K image just because I forgot about a missing brick in the rendering of a building.
But I haven't found any way to do that.
Does anyone have any hint? This might solve the specific "render patch region" that other people have been asking around, but nobody in my knowledge has found a workaround.
Suggestions are very welcome, but **if it involves saving images to files, I wouldn't consider it an answer** to this specific question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call render slots in comp, but you do have Scenes.

Render Region and other render settings are stored in the scene's data. So you can mace a Copy of your scene, linked copy might be a good option for you:

[image]

Then in comp, use two *Render Layers* nodes, with each a different scene:

[image]

Note that you can run each of them renders individually via the button right to the ViewLayer dropdown at the bottom of the node.

Comment: thanks, I'm accepting yours as an answer. I also confess I don't love the idea, since it's tricky and error prone. Let's say it's a step before having to save a rendered image apart.  
But, I guess, this is the best solution offered by today's Blender...